# Why do I need an app to plug in a Like Box?

Tags: html, web, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-likebox

So I want to create a facebook feed to connect for my facebook, from what I understand all I need is a [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages), but when I put in what information I want on the like box it says "Include the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag." The SDK wants an "app ID", but I don't want to make an app, I just want facebook feeds to show up on my web site. Is there any way to 'not' make an app and just use the like box on my website?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages while logged out. Then you won't be required to have an App ID.